# What is Subscribers message receiving mechanism if one of the subscriber fails to acknowledge in Google Pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I would to understand some concepts of Google PubSub message redelivery mechanism if one of the subscriber fails to ack the message within the ackDeadline. Some questions I would like to clarify as I am not able to find them in the the below documentation and answers online too.

1. What happens if a message M1 published to a topic with multiple subscribers and if one of the subscribers fail to ***ack***  the message due to some exception, does the message is delivered to other subscribers.
2. How to publish multiple messages M1, M2 to the same topic and Subscriber S1 wants only M1 and S2 wants M2. What if S1 fails ack.
3. Just like Kafka how does the Topic handling multiple subscription of messages at a time(Just like partitioning etc in Kafka)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to be clear about is the difference between *subscriptions* and *subscribers*. A subscription is a logical entity interested in the full feed of messages published to a topic. A subscriber is an individual client that is receiving messages for a subscription. In Kafka terms, a subscription is a consumer group and a subscriber is a consumer.

One can have multiple subscribers per subscription; at least one of the subscribers will receive each message published to the topic to which the subscription is attached. This is the model of *load balancing*: subscribers process a subset of the messages. To be able to process more messages in parallel, one brings up more subscribers.

One can also have multiple subscriptions per topic; a subscriber for each subscription will receive every message published to the topic to which the subscriptions are attached. This is the model of *fan out*. If one had a single subscriber for each subscription, then each subscriber would receive all messages.

With that, to answer your questions:

1. Assuming you mean that the subscribers are for the same subscription, then message M1 would be delivered to a subscriber for the subscription. It could be the one that did not ack the message or it could be a different one.
2. If your subscribers are only interested in a subset of the published messages, then you should create a separate subscription for each subscriber and then use [filters](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter) to define the subset of messages you want to receive in terms of the attributes attached to those messages.
3. Partitions and multiple subscriptions are not the same thing. In Cloud Pub/Sub, the user does not think in terms of partitions at all. Subscribers connect on behalf of a subscription to receive messages and messages are balanced across subscribers for the same subscription. If there are multiple subscriptions, then subscribers for each subscription will receive all messages.

Comment: : Related to Partitions I mean by Topic partitioning. How does the topic deal with the load of multiple subscribes accessing it a point of time, what if the message is too big. My main question is if one of the subscribers say S1 to a topic fail to acknowledge a message, will the message be delivered to other subscribers of the topic  (considering S1 failed to ack.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the message is too big." I covered the redelivery in the first point: "message M1 would be delivered to a subscriber for the subscription. It could be the one that did not ack the message or it could be a different one."

Comment: I mean if the message size too large(just as kafka breaks a topic message into partitions something like that). Can you please confirm if my understanding is correct.... If Subscriber 1 is not able to ack within the ackdeadline, messages will be stopped to be delivered to the other subscribers. once ackdealine of Subscriber 1 is reached/passed , other subscribers start receiving the messages

Comment: Kafka doesn't break individual messages into partitions. If a single message cannot be acknowledged, it will not stop delivery of messages to that or other subscribers. Cloud Pub/Sub does not have head-of-line blocking such that the inability to acknowledge one message prevents the delivery of other messages.